# Testing a non-trivial AngularJS app with Jasmine & Karma

Tags: unit-testing, testing, angularjs, jasmine

I'm working on a non-trivial application, with the following folder structure:

```
build (required files such as angular.js)
Gruntfile.js
karma.conf.js
logs/
node_modules/
src/
    - app/
        - app.js
        - module_name/
            - module.js
            - controllers/
                - controller1.js
                - controller2.js
            - views/
                - view1.html
    - assets/
        - 1.jpg
        - styler.css
    - components/   (plugged in modules [angular-ui, etc])
    - index.html
```

My controllers are each attached to their parent module. That module is then required in my app.js file.

I have tried writing some unit tests, but I seem to keep having trouble with dependancies, since the controller I try to test requires it's module, then that module requires another one, etc.

My question has a few parts:

1. How do I go about structuring my karma.conf.js file to include the necessary files?
   Specifically this part of the configuration:

   ```
   files: [
      'files_to_be_tested.js',
   ]
   ```
2. Using Jasmine, how do I write up a unit test with all the proper dependancies? As an example, I run the following test

Javascript

```
using 'strict'
describe('my Module', function() {
    describe('myController', function() {
        var ctrl, scope;

        beforeEach(module('myModule'));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller('myController', { $scope: scope });
        }));

        it('should work', function() {
            // Execute functionality
        })
    })
})
```

but I keep getting the error: `Unknown provider: $stateProvider`, which I think is coming from the loaded module's route configuration.

I'm beginning to wonder whether I've been separating out my controllers properly?

Comment: I'm running into the same error - did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Matt I don't specifically remember, but something that may help - make sure you are separating all your dependencies properly. Back when I asked this question I didn't really know how to do that, and I think that's why I had so much problems testing - everything was essentially depending upon everything else so it was impossible to test one area.

Comment: @Matt include the `ui.router` module to load `$stateProvider`.  `beforeEach(module('ui.router'))`

Answer (score 6):

To answer the second question:

`Unknown provider: $stateProvider` is caused by the `ui.router` module not being loaded.  To solve the problem, add `beforeEach(module('ui.router'))`

The problem arises because the controller you are loading is trying to inject `$state`

Make sure that the `ui.router` Javascript file is in the `files` list in `karma.conf.js` or the module will not be available to karma.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer to your first question. Configuring the files section;

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'components/angular/angular.js', //path to your angular.js file
  'components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',//path to your angular-mocks.js file
  'components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',//path to your angular-resource.js file
  'app/*.js',
  'app/**/*.js',
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
];
```

Try this change in your karma.conf.js and carry out your test. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Same files/patterns as your application, in the same order, then angular-mock, then your specs.
2. If you're loading a module, it should be already loaded with all its dependent modules. Since you're missing a provider and your example is calling only a controller, it could be missing from the injected controller dependencies in `$controller('myController', { $scope: scope });`.